# how to declare html table in nodejs

Tags: node.js

It gives a syntax error in . This is correct format for declaring html in nodejs. I tried all things like separately creating variable and then declaring the same error only I am getting.

```
 let mailOptions = {

                        from: 'wwwwwww@domain.com',
                        to: 'wwwwwwwww@domain.com',
                        subject: 'mail notification Test',
                        html:<html>
                        <head>
                        <style>
                        table, th, td=
                            border: 1px solid black;
                            border-collapse: collapse;

                        </style>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <table style="width:100%">
                          <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Templatename</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>TemplateContent</th>
                            <th>Activestate</th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>streamingTemplate.id.toString().toLowerCase()</td>
                            <td>streamingTemplate.is_active.toString().toLowerCase()</td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </body>
                        </html>

                            };
```

Comment: syntax error <html> unexcepted token

Comment: separetely i create var result then i define html  the same error came like result:<html>
                             SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: You need to quote your html template.

Comment: in above i didn't get any error but when i start running the app.js at the time shows app crashed.syntax error in html tag

Answer (score 0):

You need just to quote you html code like this

```
let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Fred Foo" <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ?', // plain text body
    html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
};
```

Comment: in html i add quote means it shows error all of them i tried however it gives error